# FFMPEG, player plays jerky video after encoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I've been using FFMPEG on Windows 10 for a while. To help me do my job, I have got several DOS batch files which take parameters and perform tasks like cut from beginning, blur area, mute audio etc.

I usually take big videos, extract the parts that I like using Avidemux, cut / apply filter on some parts using FFMPEG, join them using FFMPEG and then encode again to get rid of any errors (or jerkiness, etc) on my target player, which is Kodi 18.xx running on an Android TV (TCL brand).

I have done a similar process for a video that I have been doing for several years and this video seems to be out of my control. I have chopped up the video using Avidemux 2.7.2. The video has been cut at key frames. If I take a single un-encoded file, it runs perfectly on my Android TV. If I encode it using FFMPEG, it starts to jerk when played on my Android TV.

The videos always plays fine on VLC player running on my PC.

Some information that may be helpful. I can attach detailed frame information if desired.

```
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
      configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
      libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
      libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
      libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
      libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
      libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
      libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
      libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
      libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Showing info for the source file. Codec is hevc, I think FFMPEG does not have default support for?

```
ffmpeg -i _p007_cut_start.mp4 -hide_banner
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '_p007_cut_start.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
        encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
      Duration: 00:00:08.51, start: 0.006000, bitrate: 5501 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709), 1920x816 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 5091 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24390 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 401 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Showing info for the file that was encoded:

```
ffmpeg -i p007_done2.mp4 -hide_banner
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'p007_done2.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : isom
        minor_version   : 512
        compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
      Duration: 00:00:08.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3092 kb/s
        Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 10) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p10le, 1920x816 [SAR 1:1 DAR 40:17], 2743 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24390 tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : VideoHandler
        Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 345 kb/s (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

I would appreciate if someone can point to me where I am going wrong.

The command used to perform the encoding is as follows (only the library was swapped between libx264 and lib265):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -video_track_timescale 24390 -crf 23 -map 0:a -c:a aac -copyts -vsync 0 -async 0 -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

P.S. My knowledge is more based on trial-and-error and I don't understand video formats (and concepts) much except for what got me to this point.

Regards,
AK

Comment: The source is 10-bit, so ffmpeg has converted to 10-bit H.264 for which your player may not be performant. Encode to x264 8-bit by adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The video that I had encoded with libx264, I re-encoded with libx265 and the problem has gone away.

But I am still keen to know why encoding with libx264 causes the video to be jerky.

Regards,
AK

Comment: What was your FFmpeg commands for both situations (not working h264, **vs** the working h265)? Use the [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63762608/edit) button to add that info to your Question.

Comment: I have edited and added the command. Its towards the end of my original post.